# Android : Getting RuntimeException on AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-asynctask, runtimeexception

In the code I try to read from a web service  with an http client. Then I want to write the Responce Phrase of the http responce to a text view. The UI is accessed through onPostExecute() so I don't know why I get this exception.

This is the code:

```
public class CustomersScreen extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.customersscreen);
}

public void LoginClicked(View view) {
    new Get_data().execute("http://localhost:51982/WcfDataService1.svc/Genre");
}

private class Get_data extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        //InputStream instream = null;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url[0]);
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(request);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String phrase = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

        return phrase;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String phrase) {
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        t.setText(phrase);
    }

}
```

}

and the log cat :

```
09-28 09:43:34.239: E/AndroidRuntime(679): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-28 09:43:34.239: E/AndroidRuntime(679): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-28 09:43:34.239: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
09-28 09:43:34.239: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
09-28 09:43:34.239: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
09-28 09:43:34.239: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
09-28 09:43:34.239: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-28 09:43:34.239: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
09-28 09:43:34.239: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
09-28 09:43:34.239: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
09-28 09:43:34.239: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-28 09:43:34.239: E/AndroidRuntime(679): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 09:43:34.239: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at com.test.CustomersScreen$Get_data.doInBackground(CustomersScreen.java:46)
09-28 09:43:34.239: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at com.test.CustomersScreen$Get_data.doInBackground(CustomersScreen.java:1)
09-28 09:43:34.239: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
09-28 09:43:34.239: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-28 09:43:34.239: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  ... 5 more
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.test.CustomersScreen$Get_data.doInBackground(CustomersScreen.java:46)`. Check the statement at line 46 of CustomersScreen.java

Comment: Why don't you just debug?  Put a breakpoint in line 46 of the CustomersScreen class then run it.  I bet it's the t.setText(phrase) and t is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 09:43:34.239: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at com.test.CustomersScreen$Get_data.doInBackground(CustomersScreen.java:46)
```

You have a NPE in line 46 of your class. The code, posted lacks some lines obviously, but I suppose it's this line `String phrase = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();` as `response` would be `null` if anything goes wrong with the `httpclient.execute(request);`

So, just put that line within the `try/catch` block as well and add a simple `return null;` at the end of the method instead.

Comment: thanks man that really helped. Seems my response = httpclient.execute(request); gets an HttpHostConnectionException I am trying to figure out now. It says connection to http://localhost:51982 refused

Comment: Well, localhost would be the Android device itself -- you have to provide the IP address (but not 127.0.0.1), even if you're testing against a local server.

Comment: I tried the local IP address cause the server is on the same computer and have the same exception. So propably the internet IP address is what is needed

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses this is the address needed. Finnaly it works

Comment: If the server is localhost, you have to use 10.0.2.2 as ip. This ip is treated as localhost by emulator.